# Conditionally set multiple settings based on another setting's value in an SBT AutoPlugin

Tags: sbt

I want my AutoPlugin to expose one setting which, if set, causes ≈5 other settings to also be set to corresponding values.

Specifically, if a downstream build sets a non-empty `shadedDeps`:

```
val shadedDeps = settingKey[Seq[ModuleID]]("When set, the main JAR produced will include these libraries shaded")
```

then I want to automatically set several `assembly`-related settings (e.g. `assemblyExcludedJars`, `assemblyJarName`, `artifactClassifier`).

I can't find a way to do this because the `AutoPlugin.projectSettings` method cannot access `shadedDeps.value` (attempting to do so gives the "`value can only be used within a task or setting macro`" error).

The best I've come up with is having my plugin also define a setting like:

```
val extraAssemblySettings = settingKey[Seq[Def.Setting[_]]]("…")
```

and then conditionally loading that setting with the assembly-settings I want, and then evaluating

```
extraAssemblySettings
```

in downstream projects' `build.sbt`. Ideally I'd be able to skip that last step and just have the setting of `shadedDeps` trigger everything.

Something about my (very naive) mental model of how SBT settings work is clearly amiss, as this seems like it should be trivial and yet I've scoured the internet and come up empty.

Comment: Can you show all the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

At some point later I figured this out; [this `addSparkDeps` block](https://github.com/hammerlab/sbt-parent/blob/3.2.0/src/main/scala/org/hammerlab/sbt/plugin/Spark.scala#L26-L39) in my kitchen-sink project-boilerplate plugin is an example of one incantation that can be placed in a downstream `build.sbt` and that unrolls to multiple settings. [Here's an example usage](https://github.com/hammerlab/genomic-loci/blob/2.0.1/build.sbt#L6).